# Laravel's Hash missing argument?

Tags: php, hash, laravel-5

I'm getting a weird error in Laravel 5.3's hash mechanism.

```
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher::check(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Missionseek2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 237 and defined
```

This is the code that defines it.

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request){

        $val = DB::table('ministry')->where('Username', Input::get('Username'))->first();

        if ($val && Hash::check(Input::get('Password', $val->Password))) {
            return redirect()->route('agencydash');
        } return 'failed';
       // if (Auth::attempt(['Username' => $request['Username'], 'Password' => $request['Password']])) {
       //     return redirect()->route('agencydash');
       // }
        //return redirect()->back();
    }
```

What's going on here? I feel like it's not getting the password value from the database and so we're getting an error, but I'm not sure why. The name's are correct.

Comment: try if ($val && Hash::check(Input::get('Password'), $val->Password))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing 2 argument in Input::get() instead of check(). You have to correct brackets positions

```
if ($val && Hash::check(Input::get('Password'), $val->Password))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your parenthesis is not in the right place

You have  :

`Hash::check(Input::get('Password', $val->Password))`

And I think you have to move your parenthesis to :

`Hash::check(Input::get('Password'), $val->Password)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Hash::check works, but here

```
Hash::check(Input::get('Password', $val->Password))
```

you gave it only one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have something wrong in your parentheses.

```
if ($val && Hash::check(Input::get('Password', $val->Password)))
```

becomes

```
if ($val && Hash::check(Input::get('Password'), $val->Password))
```